# If $p(n) := \sum_{i=0}^ka_in^i$ where $a_i\in\mathbb{N}, a_k \ne 0$ AND $k \ge 2$, is $L = \{0^n1^{p(n)} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I have the really strong feeling it is indeed NOT context-free, since the language $1^{n^k}$ for $k\ge 2$ is not context free (proven by the pumping lemma) and, in a sense, "the order of magnitude" of the number of 1s will always supercede the order of the number of 0s, but I really can't find an exhaustive proof for the global case where $p(n)$ is any polynomial of degree $k$. Any advice is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Not at all, I took a look and I kind of get why it could be applicable here, but couldn't really grasp it's idea and therefore usage just now.. It would be nice if you could hint on the use case a bit more. ^^

Comment: You can prove your claim using Parikh's theorem. In particular, $P(L)$ is not semi-linear in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is context-free then so is the language $L'$ obtained from $L$ by changing all $1$'s to $0$'s. Since $L'$ is unary, if it is context-free then it is actually regular. Moreover, in that case the set $N = \{ n : 0^n \in L' \}$ is eventually periodic. Consequently, $N$ is either finite or has positive lower density (there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that for large $n$, $|N \cap [n]| \geq \alpha n$). In your case, $N$ is infinite but has upper density zero ($|N \cap [n]|/n \to 0$; in fact $|N \cap [n]| = O(n^{1/k})$), and so $L$ is not context-free.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the pumping lemma for CFL?
Let P be the pumping constant for the language. Prove that
p(P + 1) - p(P) >= P for all polynomials with degree greater than 1 and nonzero positive coefficients and try to use that fact to break the lemma. Good luck ^^